# Lightning popover - show nubbin in the right side

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, popover, lightning-overlaylibrary

I am using popover with lightning:overlayLibrary. The standard side of the nubbin is on the left. and looks like this:

[image]

I am trying change it to right. This is how I'm using it:

```
  component.find('overlayLib').showCustomPopover({
                        body:modalBody,
                        referenceSelector:".mypopover",
                        cssClass:"slds-nubbin_right,no-pointer",
                    })
```

with the following css:

```
.THIS.no-pointer .pointer { 
    visibility: hidden !important; 
}
```

As you could see, I added the classes "slds-nubbin_right,no-pointer" in order to remove the left nubbin and show the right nubbin (as written in the documentation) and this is the result i get:

[image]

This is from the documentation:

[image]

How can I put the nubbin only in the right side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to position LEFT when showing popover using lightning:overlayLibrary](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224819/unable-to-position-left-when-showing-popover-using-lightningoverlaylibrary)

Comment: You can use the custom Strike component: http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikePopover and set the `placement` to `auto left`

Comment: @tsalb How is this a duplicate if the post you linked isn't solved?

Comment: @Salesforce_Noobie because the answer is you can't do anything about it until Salesforce fixes it.